# Rails association when you have a drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a collection select to display all the categories on the website.

```
<%= form.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select category" %>
```

I also included category_id in the permit params

```
def portfolio_params
  params.require(:portfolio).permit(:name, :client, :completed, :about,:square, :cover, :category_id)
end
```

Shouldn't it form the association using the create method like this

```
 def create
  @portfolio = Portfolio.new(portfolio_params)
  @test = portfolio_params[:category_id]
  respond_to do |format|
   if @portfolio.save
    format.html { redirect_to @portfolio, notice: 'Portfolio was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @portfolio }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @portfolio.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

But when I look at the test variable it shows null. I am really puzzled about this. I am using rails 5 and ruby 2.3.0

Here are the params

```
<ActionController::Parameters 
  {"utf8"=>"✓", 
   "authenticity_token"=>"XzyeAtZF5mOXG2GdRIrlmRcPwhruAOfrvzIWTD9QUsIJ4GMytB6s38oM3NT9RIwr+B8osJWasmg2Qd0VoROTiw==", 
   "portfolio"=><ActionController::Parameters
     {"name"=>"test", 
      "client"=>"", 
      "completed(1i)"=>"2017", 
      "completed(2i)"=>"5", 
      "completed(3i)"=>"17", 
      "about"=>"", 
      "categoy_id"=>"3"} permitted: false>, 
   "commit"=>"Create Portfolio", 
   "controller"=>"portfolios", 
   "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

Comment: `categoy_id ` is it a typo when you wrote the question?

Comment: Yes it it a typo

Comment: I was told not to use params for security and use portfolio_params instead

Comment: I still get the same thing

Comment: That does not work too

Comment: Could you provide a repo?

Comment: You mean the `@test` variable is null in create method?

Comment: params: categories: [:id]